# FlipProgressDialog doesn´t work

Tags: java, android

Hey guys I have a problem, my FlipProgressDialog dosen´t work.

So this is part code:

```
List<Integer> imageList = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_post);

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_STORAGE);


    imageList.add(R.drawable.imageOne);
    imageList.add(R.drawable.imageTwo);
```

This button will start the startPosting(); method:

```
btnSubmitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            startPosting();

        }
    })
```

This is the startPosting(); method:

```
public void startPosting() {

    showFlipProgressDialog("rotationY");

    String title_val = mTitle.getText().toString().trim();
    String shortDesc_val = mShortDescription.getText().toString().trim();
    String story_val = mStory.getText().toString().trim();

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(title_val) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(shortDesc_val) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(story_val)){

        StorageReference filepath = mStorage.child("Images").child(mImageUri.getLastPathSegment());

        filepath.putFile(mImageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                @SuppressWarnings("VisibleForTests")
                Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

As you can see the startPosting(); method will start the showFlipProgressDialog("rotationY"); method.

This is the showFlipProgressDialog("rotationY"); method:

```
public void showFlipProgressDialog(String orientation) {

    FlipProgressDialog flip = new FlipProgressDialog();
    flip.setImageList(imageList);
    flip.setOrientation(orientation);
    flip.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF4081"));
    flip.setDimAmount(0.8f);
    flip.setBackgroundAlpha(1.0f);
    flip.setCornerRadius(32);
}
```

All it´s working fine, but the FlipProgressDialog never appear.

Also I want to know how to dismiss the FlipProgressDialog, Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show dialog

```
flip.show(getFragmentManager(),"flip");
```

To dismiss dialog

```
flip.dismiss();
```

Comment: When i put: flip.show(getFragmentManager(),"flip");
on the startPosting(); method, the first word flip is in color red, how can i solve this?